# Find the work done.

Tags: integration, physics

**Problem:**  An object below the surface of the earth is attracted by a gravitational force that is directly proportional to the square of the distance from the object to the center of the earth. Set up and analyze a model to find the work done in lifting an object weighing $P$ lb from a depth of $s$ feet (below the surface). Assume that the earth's radius is $4000$ mi and that $P$ is constant between $s$ and the surface.

**My Attempt:** The gravitational force $F=kx^2$, where $k$ is the constant of proportionality and $x$ is the distance from the center of the earth. The object weighs $P$ lbs and therefore $$P=k(4000-s)^2$$ $$\implies k=\frac{P}{(4000-s)^2}.$$ Thus the work done is $$W=\int_{4000-s}^{4000}Fdx=\int_{4000-s}^{4000}\frac{Px^2}{(4000-s)^2}dx$$
$$=\frac{P}{(4000-s)^2}\left[\frac{x^3}{3}\right]_{4000}^{4000-s}=\frac{P}{3}\left(4000-s\right)-\frac{4000^3P}{3(4000-s)^2}.$$

However, the answer is $$4000^2P\left(\frac{1}{4000}-\frac{1}{s}\right)\text{mi-lb.}$$

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: force of gravity is $k/x^2$, not $kx^2$.

Comment: @Simon But the question has written directly proportional, not inversely proportional.

Comment: Ah I see. Though the question is quite strange: (1) The "weight" $P$ of an object is the same as the gravitational force acting on it. If we assume that $P$ is constant (as stated in the question), the answer would be $W=s\cdot P$. (2) if you use $k=P/4000^2$ (without the $-s$ part), your answer will be nicer but still not your stated solution. (3) your stated solution can't possilby be true, because in the $s=0$ case the answer must be $0$ (because lifting an object $0$ distance takes $0$ work in all cases).

Comment: I think the transcription of the problem is not quite right. I've found a model that get the stated solution and it's based in the formula Newton gave for the gravitational attraction.

Comment: @Simon Indeed, the force is a linear one $\propto x$ because the force is coming from the sphere 'beneath $x$' . Namely, volume $\propto x^{3}$ and force $\propto 1/x^{2}$ yields the force $\propto x^{3} \times \left(1/x^{2}\right) = x$. The earth portion 'above' $x$ doesn't apply any force. See my answer below.

Answer (score -1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> $\ds{\oplus:\ \mbox{Earth}\,,\ M_{\oplus}:\ \mbox{Earth Mass}\,,\ R_{\oplus}:\ \mbox{Earth Radius}\,,\ g = 9.8\ \mrm{m/sec^{2}}\,,\ m: \mbox{Body Mass} }$.

$\ds{x}$ is the distance from the body, of mass $\ds{m}$, to the *Earth Center*. $\ds{G}$ is the *Gravitational Constant*. It's assumed the trajectory ia a straight line from $\ds{R_{\oplus} - s}$ to $\ds{R_{\oplus}}$
( the *Earth Surface* ) with the origin at the Earth Center.

The *Earth Mass Density* is given by
$\ds{{M_{\oplus} \over 4\pi R_{\oplus}^{3}/3}}$ which assumes the Earth as a homogeneous sphere of radius $\ds{R_{\oplus}}$.
\begin{align}
\mbox{Force} & =
G\,\bracks{\pars{M_{\oplus} \over 4\pi R_{\oplus}^{3}/3}\pars{{4 \over 3}\,\pi x^{3}}}
{m \over x^{2}} =
m\,\
\overbrace{{GM_{\oplus} \over R_{\oplus}^{2}}}^{\ds{=\ g}}\,\
{x \over R_{\oplus}} =
mg\,{x \over R_{\oplus}}
\\[5mm]
\mbox{Work} & =
\int_{R_{\oplus} - s}^{R_{\oplus}}mg\,{x \over R_{\oplus}}\,\dd x
=
mg\,{R_{\oplus}^{2} - \pars{R_{\oplus} - s}^{2} \over 2R_{\oplus}} =
\bbx{\ds{{s \over R_{\oplus}}\,\pars{1 - {1 \over 2}\,{s \over R_{\oplus}}}\,mgR_{\oplus}}}
\end{align}

Comment: So, where does that square come from?

Comment: @RafaBudría What square ?.

Comment: This one $F=kx^2$ Of course this question is almost out of topic, but I wondered about what dependence for the force make the stated solution appear. I've found it can be making $F=-k/x^2$ and $s$ not the depth but the distance to the center.

Comment: @RafaBudría This is a $\texttt{characteristic}$ of the force $\displaystyle\propto {1 \over r^{\color{#f00}{2}}}$. The force is coming from the sphere of radius $x$. The mass of that sphere is proportional to $x^{3}$ which later it's divided by $x^{2}$. The question was 'ill-posed' at the very beginning.

Comment: @Shrey Aryan. Yes, Felix, I understood that, thanks. Maybe the OP could revise the wording.